# How to find the full IP to my PC on work network for RDP

Tags: windows, windows-7, ip, remote-desktop, rdp

I need to access my work computer from my home computer. Both run Windows 7. I have completely setup both computers to run RDP.

I just can't figure out how to connect to my work computer. When I run the Remote Desktop Connection Client its asks for a computer name or IP. I know what the IP for the network is at the office where my computer is but that isn't enough info to be able to connect to my computer there.

We have another computer setup for RDP at our office (I didn't set it up though) and I can RDP to it just fine from home because I have the full IP to that computer. For Example, I can connect by using 555.555.555.555:**22737**, note the bolded part of the number at the end.

How do I figure out what that bold number would be for my computer on the network? If that is not something in place, how do I set it up?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That 22737 is actually the port number that you are rdping in to your public IP address. Your network administrator probably has Network Address Translation turned on for that specific port to translate your public address + thta port number to the correct ip address of that workstation.

You'll need to speak to your network admin to see if he could do the same for your computer.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Well, he got fired... and we are kinda hanging for a server admin right now. That is why I am posting in this forum. "If that is not something in place, how do I set it up?"

Comment: Now that question is a lot more complicated. What is the brand of firewall do you have setup and what's the model number?

In short, you'll need to map a new port, lets say 22738. Have port translation from your public IP and port, to the destionation IP (the ip of the computer on your network) and translate the port to 3389. Which is the default RDP port.

Comment: I don't recommend changing your firewall setup at work without a much better understanding. Far too easy to open up holes.